# How to convert minutes to hours in google sheets?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, time, google-sheets-formula, average

I have some data expressed in minutes. I retrieve the average value using this formula:

```
=QUERY(A3:D1074,"select C, avg (D) group by C")
```

An example value I receive is `351.333333333333` (minutes).

Then I convert it to hours using this formula:

```
=QUOTIENT(N3,60) & ":" & IF(LEN(MOD(N3,60))=1,0,"") & MOD(N3,60)
```

The result i get is `5:51.3333333333333` (hours:minutes)

Now I'm unable to make a graph using the values expressed in hours. I see *invalid type* error when I enter the data to be used in graph.

How can I use convert the time values from minutes to hours and still be able to use it in a graph?

[image]

[image]

Comment: QUERY is not excel function, it is google-sheet function.

Comment: just divide by 60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=TEXT(E2/24/60/60; "mm:ss")
```

[image]

or directly:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(QUERY(A3:D, "select avg(D) group by C label avg(D)''")/24/60/60, "[mm]:ss"))
```

[image]

---

### UPDATE:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tried both  formulas....but still its showing invalid type when tried to enter data range in graph

Comment: @vasu can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Sry I cant share that.. its containing the sensitive information.. but i have added a scrrenshot at the top..

Comment: @vasu you can try to drop `TEXT` and format it internally `=INDEX(QUERY(A3:D, "select avg(D) group by C label avg(D)''")/24/60/60)`

Comment: By using this formula  ..i receive different values ...but now I'm able to enter the data range in graph...

Comment: @vasu answer updated

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1pkE.png

Comment: @vasu select your AVG IN HRS column and format it as time internally

Comment: I dont know how to do format it to time , can you please help me with that.

Comment: @vasu here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16LUTPtZjfL4wfjO4H-HZY0QN2vCJFO-0THk3kkYTar4/copy

Answer (score 3):

The data you get after converting to hours is text, because you concatenate numbers (hours, minutes) with text (`:`). This can be easily checked by using the `TYPE()` formula on the result of your conversion: it returns 2, meaning it is text data (1 would be numerical data).

I would suggest simply dividing the data in minutes by 60 and use that in the graph, it should work as it will be numerical data.